# importing csv file to list issue

Tags: python, list, csv

Hi i am trying to import this csv file to a list:

```
00cd3de3903a1dd0c5d10a4da5298088
0164d6463da0f5557c18ee5bf3fa40c6
021471774a61276bca2acc70d2605448
025faee9578c97fbaa0da61d55691758
04dd55ae5d18babc028a8410ca34ce10
0524579c38b45ce3f90865a91d4318a4
05a00c320754934782ec5dec1d5c0476
068ed52dae623cbd44c2198cb0eecda3
07dbd191187a3bfbd1d935cabdd82e24
0c3a1172e21000fe43a5b7894f3e0687
```

the code looks like this:

```
with open('\\\\ntsrv1\\Indicators_for_Siem\\IOC1.csv', 'r', ) as temp_file:
    readCSV = csv.reader(temp_file, delimiter=',')

for row in readCSV:
    new_list.append(row)
```

the output looks like this:

```
[['00cd3de3903a1dd0c5d10a4da5298088'], ['0164d6463da0f5557c18ee5bf3fa40c6'],      ['021471774a61276bca2acc70d2605448'], ['025faee9578c97fbaa0da61d55691758'],   ['04dd55ae5d18babc028a8410ca34ce10'], ['0524579c38b45ce3f90865a91d4318a4'], ['05a00c320754934782ec5dec1d5c0476'], ['068ed52dae623cbd44c2198cb0eecda3'], ['07dbd191187a3bfbd1d935cabdd82e24'], ['0c3a1172e21000fe43a5b7894f3e0687']]
```

not it looks like a list of lists

and i am looking for a pattern of singe list for example:

```
['value1','value2','value3','value4']
```

thank you for your assistance

Comment: change to `new_list.append(row[0])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The row variable is a list.

```
import csv
new_list = []
with open('input.csv', 'r') as temp_file:
    readCSV = csv.reader(temp_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        new_list.append(row[0])
print(new_list)
```

Will output:

```
['00cd3de3903a1dd0c5d10a4da5298088', '0164d6463da0f5557c18ee5bf3fa40c6', '021471774a61276bca2acc70d2605448', '025faee9578c97fbaa0da61d55691758', '04dd55ae5d18babc028a8410ca34ce10', '0524579c38b45ce3f90865a91d4318a4', '05a00c320754934782ec5dec1d5c0476', '068ed52dae623cbd44c2198cb0eecda3', '07dbd191187a3bfbd1d935cabdd82e24', '0c3a1172e21000fe43a5b7894f3e0687']
```

Answer (score 2):

That is not a CSV. Just use:

```
with open('input.csv') as temp_file:
    new_list = temp_file.read().splitlines()
```

Comment: Your solution is more elegant. I posted code that indicated a specific point in the original code. Upvoting :)